# Constructors in case of multi-inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

this may be a stupid question but I'm dealingthe first time with multi-inheritance.

Single-inheritance is defined and works like this:

```
class Canvas3D : public CanvasBase
{
...
```

Here Canvas3D inherits from CanvasBase and therefore the base-constructor has to be called this way on construction:

```
Canvas3D::Canvas3D(window* parent)
         :CanvasBase(parent)
{
...
```

Now Canvas3D needs to inherit from two base classes:

```
class Canvas3D : public CanvasBase, public GLCanvas
{
...
```

How do I call the base-constructor of GLCanvas when it does not provide a default constructor? These variants do not work:

```
Canvas3D::Canvas3D(window* parent)
         :CanvasBase(parent)
         ,GlCanvas(parent)
{
...

Canvas3D::Canvas3D(window* parent)
         :CanvasBase(parent)
         :GlCanvas(parent)
{
...
```

Comment: The comma syntax is the right one to use. [deleting now-irrelevant bits]

Comment: underscore_d: sorry, this is a typo in my example - hvae corrected it!

Comment: OK. Does it still produce an error when using the comma-separated initialiser list? If so, please quote the exact message.

Comment: underscore_d: no, that was the problem, I did the same crap in my program - thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Canvas3D` constructor needs to take in the parameters to construct the `GLCanvas` part and pass them to the `GLCanvas` constructor.

```
Canvas3D::Canvas3D(window* parent, GLCanvas_Parameters) : 
    CanvasBase(parent), GlCanvas(GLCanvas_Parameters)
{
    //...
}
```